# A question about indecomposable module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a possibly non-commutative ring with unity and $M$ be an (left) $R$-module.

Suppose $M$ is indecomposable, i.e. $M$ can not be written as direct sum of two proper submodules.

Is it true that $M=Rm$ for some $m\in M$?

--

If $M$ is irreducible, than any non-zero $m$ works; but I was not able to handle the above situation. Any hint for it?

Comment: Try looking at the question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140650/indecomposable-module-which-is-not-cyclic

Comment: how about $\mathbb{Q}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module? it's a good exercise to show that this module is (i) not cyclic, and (ii) not indecomposable